# Unable to register ec2 instance into ECS using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, user-data

I am unable to register the ec2 instance into the ecs cluster, I have created the cluster, service and registered the task into it. But the ec2 instance is not registered. I have given the userdata to register the instance into the cluster but unable to register it. I am attaching the files which are needed. Ec2 instance are provisioning just not registering to the ECS cluster. I am implementing module wise structure. I am attaching the screenshot at the end of the question

Autoscaling:

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "ec2" {
  image_id             = var.image_id
  instance_type        = var.instance_type
  name                 = "ec2-${terraform.workspace}"
  user_data            = <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo 'ECS_CLUSTER=${var.cluster_name.name}' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo 'ECS_DISABLE_PRIVILEGED=true' >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
EOF
  key_name             = var.key_name
  iam_instance_profile = var.instance_profile
  security_groups      = [aws_security_group.webserver.id]

}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg" {
  vpc_zone_identifier       = var.public_subnet
  desired_capacity          = 2
  max_size                  = 2
  min_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 300
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.ec2.name
  target_group_arns         = [var.tg.arn]

}

resource "aws_security_group" "webserver" {
  name        = "webserver-${terraform.workspace}"
  description = "Allow internet traffic"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    description = "incoming for ec2-instance"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = -1
    security_groups = [var.alb_sg]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "webserver-sg"
  }

}
output "ec2_sg" {
  value = aws_security_group.webserver.id
}
```

Cluster:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "wordpress-${terraform.workspace}"
}
output "cluster" {
  value = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id
}
output "cluster1" {
  value = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster
}
```

Service:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "wordpress" {
  name                = "Wordpress-${terraform.workspace}"
  cluster             = var.cluster
  task_definition     = var.task.id
  desired_count       = 2
  scheduling_strategy = "REPLICA"

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = var.tg.arn
    container_name   = "wordpress"
    container_port   = 80
  }
  deployment_controller {
    type = "ECS"
  }
}
```

Task:

```
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/template/containerdef.json")}"
  vars = {
    rds_endpoint = "${var.rds_endpoint}"
    name         = "${var.name}"
    username     = "${var.username}"
    password     = "${var.password}"
  }
}
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task" {
  family                   = "wordpress"
  container_definitions    = "${data.template_file.init.rendered}"
  network_mode             = "bridge"
  requires_compatibilities = ["EC2"]
  memory                   = "1GB"
  cpu                      = "1 vCPU"
  task_role_arn            = var.task_execution.arn
}
```

main.tf

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "name" {
  name = "Dbname"
}
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "password" {
  name = "db_password"
}

module "my_vpc" {
  source            = "./modules/vpc"
  vpc_cidr          = var.vpc_cidr
  public_subnet     = var.public_subnet
  private_subnet    = var.private_subnet
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
}

module "db" {
  source            = "./modules/rds"
  ec2_sg            = "${module.autoscaling.ec2_sg}"
  allocated_storage = var.db_allocated_storage
  storage_type      = var.db_storage_type
  engine            = var.db_engine
  engine_version    = var.db_engine_version
  instance_class    = var.db_instance_class
  name              = data.aws_ssm_parameter.name.value
  username          = data.aws_ssm_parameter.name.value
  password          = data.aws_ssm_parameter.password.value
  vpc_id            = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
  public_subnet     = "${module.my_vpc.public_subnets_ids}"
}
module "alb" {
  source        = "./modules/alb"
  vpc_id        = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
  public_subnet = "${module.my_vpc.public_subnets_ids}"
}
module "task" {
  source         = "./modules/task"
  name           = data.aws_ssm_parameter.name.value
  username       = data.aws_ssm_parameter.name.value
  password       = data.aws_ssm_parameter.password.value
  rds_endpoint   = "${module.db.rds_endpoint}"
  task_execution = "${module.role.task_execution}"
}
module "autoscaling" {
  source = "./modules/autoscaling"
  vpc_id = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
  #public_subnet = "${module.my_vpc.public_subnets_ids}"
  tg               = "${module.alb.tg}"
  image_id         = var.image_id
  instance_type    = var.instance_type
  alb_sg           = "${module.alb.alb_sg}"
  public_subnet    = "${module.my_vpc.public_subnets_ids}"
  instance_profile = "${module.role.instance_profile}"
  key_name         = var.key_name
  cluster_name     = "${module.cluster.cluster1}"
}
module "role" {
  source = "./modules/Iam_role"
}
module "cluster" {
  source = "./modules/Ecs-cluster"
}
module "service" {
  source  = "./modules/services"
  cluster = "${module.cluster.cluster}"
  tg      = "${module.alb.tg}"
  task    = "${module.task.task}"
}
```

ec2-instance role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "container_instance" {
  name               = "container_instance-${terraform.workspace}"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

  tags = {
    tag-key = "tag-value"
  }

}
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ec2_instance_role" {
  name = "iam_instance_profile-${terraform.workspace}"
  role = aws_iam_role.container_instance.name
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2_instance" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.container_instance.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What is `var.cluster_name.name`? is it the same as `wordpress-${terraform.workspace}`?

Comment: Similarly, what is `var.cluster`? Is it coming from a module, or is it manually provided?

Comment: I am passing the name of cluster to the userdata.

Comment: `var.cluster` gives the id of the cluster, I have defined it in the output of cluster.tf file

Comment: I have added the `main.tf` file in which I am calling the modules for better understanding. The values like `ami_id` or `key_name` are called from another var file df.vars ignore these values. Just wanted to know why ec2 instance is not registering

Comment: Have you logged to the instance, and inspected `/etc/ecs/ecs.config`? Does it correctly show the cluster name. Also your screenshot is about tasks, not container instances. Also do you use ECS optimized AMI image on the instance?

Comment: I have used ecs optimized ami, I haven't ssh to the instance will check them too. Does my userdata seems fine or is it missing something?

Comment: Looks ok, but there is so much code that its difficult to grasp what's happening at first.

Comment: I have ran the `terraform apply` command again will let you know after ssh-ing into the instance

Comment: I have ssh into the instance it is getting the cluster name `ECS_CLUSTER=wordpress-default ECS_DISABLE_PRIVILEGED=true
`

Comment: when I run `docker ps` inside the instance it doesnot shows the wordpress container

Comment: If the instance does not register with cluster, it will not run anything. What about instance role? Is it correct and has `AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole`?

Comment: I have added the ec2 instance role file which I am using

Comment: Role looks fine. So the only other reason I can think  now of why an instance would not register with cluster is lack of internet connectivity. But then if you ssh to it, then it must be fine.

Comment: `task_role_arn  = var.instance_profile.arn`  `execution_role_arn       = var.task_execution.arn` do I have to specify both role in task `main.tf`?

Comment: It depends. But the problem is with the container instances, as you wrote in the title? Everything else is irrelevant if the cluster has no instances.

Comment: `output "instance_profile" {value = aws_iam_instance_profile.ec2_instance_role}` am I referencing the output right later to be used in auto-scaling launch config?

Comment: You should be using its profile name in  `iam_instance_profile`. For example, `var.instance_profile.name`. But go to instance, and check its instance role. Its strange it woudn't error out if you used wrong profile name.

Comment: the IAM role of instance shows this `container_instance-default` which is correct I think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219940/discussion-between-marcin-and-shifa).

Comment: In task.tf what should I use  ` task_role_arn  = var.instance_profile.arn` `execution_role_arn  = var.task_execution.arn` or should I use both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the chat discussion.

The issue could be caused by using incorrect instance profile:

```
iam_instance_profile = var.instance_profile.name
```

The important thing is that, now the two instances are **correctly registered** with the cluster.